# php multidimensional array - extracting keys

Tags: php, arrays

i have a multidimensional array
the first two statements of code work fine... notice them below...

```
      echo $arrayObjects['name'].'<br>';
      echo $arrayObjects['ipv4']['10.14.2.22']['type'].'<br>';
```

but i want to be able to return the keys in the ipv4 array, instead of having to hard code them like i did above. when i do the following:

```
      print_r( array_keys($arrayObjects['ipv4']));
```

I get the following output:

```
         Array ( [0] => 10.14.2.22 )
```

which is great.  but how do i get the ip address returned to me as a variable?

Comment: `$ips = array_keys($arrayObjects['ipv4']); $ip = $ips[0]; var_dump($ip);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

First Element:

```
$ip_address = array_shift(array_keys($arrayObjects['ipv4']));
```

Each Element:

```
foreach($arrayObjects['ipv4'] as $ip_address => $value){
    print_r($ip_address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($arrayObjects['ipv4'] as $key => $value)
{
    // Echo out the key OR save it to another variable..
    echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $arrayObjects['ipv4'] as $ip => $content )
{
 echo $ip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
current(array_keys($arrayObjects['ipv4']));
```

This simply extracts the first element out of any array when used like this.

The value returned from this should be '10.14.2.22'

http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php